# How to establish the range of $x$ in which the exponential tower $x^x$, $x^{x^x}$, ... converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n = x^{a_{n-1}}$ with $x \in \mathbb R$. That means $x_n = \underbrace{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^\cdot}}}}}}}_{\text{$n$ times}} $

Wikipedia says $a_n$ converges if and only if $x \in [\frac{1}{e^e}, e^\frac{1}{e}]$. I asked myself how that statemand can be proved:

What I found out: $a = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$  implies $x^a = a$ which can also be written as $x=a^\frac{1}{a}$. If you now define $f(a) = a^\frac{1}{a}$ you can find the global maximum/minimum and the domain. The domain will be the limits of $a_n$ and the maximum/minimum will be the valid values $x$ for which $a_n$ converges. Is this correct?

EDIT: As Quang Hoang pointed out I have only one direction, now I am interested in the proof the other direction of the 'if and only if'.

Comment: I think it's correct, but only shows the "only if" part. That is: if the sequence is convergent, then $x \in[e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but can we replace 'implies' by 'is equivalent'? I think that is the point I am still not sure about.

Comment: I think not. For the converse, you may want to consider the cases $x>1$ and $x<1$ and show that $a_n$ is increasing/decreasing and bounded.